# Hibernate load children by child

Tags: hibernate, jboss, lazy-loading, wildfly, dao

maybe someone knows a better solution for my problem. 
Hibernate is not loading all children, when the parent object is called from one child before:

```
Parent = Child.getParent();
List<Child> children = Parent.getChildren(); //Only one child inside list
```

My solution at this time is to get the parentId from the given child and load the parent object from DAO again. And now, all children can be called:

```
String parentId = Child.getParentId();
Parent parent = parentDao.findById(parentId);     
List<Child> children = Parent.getChildren(); //Every child is in list
```

Maybe there is a better way instead of the DAO call?!

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is the getParent() method from the child class:

```
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PARENT", referencedColumnName = "ID_PARENT", insertable = false,
          updatable = false, nullable = false)})
  public Parent getParent() {
    return this.parent;
  }
```

and here is the getChildren() method from the parent class:

```
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  @OrderBy("order ASC")
  public Set<Children> getChildren() {
    return this.children;
  }
```

Comment: Without seeing what the `getParent()` and `getChildren()` methods look like it's tough to say what the issue might be. From the code samples they look like static methods which may be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But there is nothing static in the classes. The variables are protected. But i think that's not the problem.